# PHP Multidimensional Array Validation

Tags: php, arrays, validation, multidimensional-array

I've been looking for an answer but can't quite find one so here's my case. I have the following array:

```
$pages = array(
   'page-one'=>range(1,9),
   'page-two'=>range(1,3),
   'page-three'=>range(5,9)
);
```

And I'd like to validate user's access permission to the page based on his role id, so, let's say John (role id=2) wants to visit the page-two. So, how can I validate the page exists and he owns a valid role.

I've tried something like...

```
foreach ($pages as $page=>$roles) {
   if (given-page==$page) {
      // Then validate role id
      if (in_array(given-role,$roles)) {
         include('the-page');
      } else {
         include('403-page');
      }
   } else {
      include('404-page');
   }
}
```

However it always shows the 404-page.How can I validate both variables (page and role id) with that array structure?

Thanks,
Carlos

Comment: Check your given-page variable. Echo it in loop start. `foreach ($pages as $page=>$roles) { echo "{given-page}==$page<br>"; /*...*/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pages = array(
   'page-one'=>range(1,9),
   'page-two'=>range(1,3),
   'page-three'=>range(5,9)
);
$givenpage = "page-one";
$givenrole = 2;

if(isset($pages[$givenpage])) {
    if(in_array($givenrole, $pages[$givenpage])) {
        include $givenpage;
    }
    else {
        include "403-page";
    }
}
else {
    include "404-page";
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Tanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution. It could be solved like...

```
if (!isset($pages[given-page])) {
   include(404-page);
} else if (isset($pages[given-page]) && in_array(given-role,$pages[given-page])) {
   include(given-page);
} else {
   include(403-page);
}
```

Nevertheless, if you think there's a better way, please share it.

Thanks!